# understanding svg css style

Tags: css, html, svg

I'm trying to understand how the css styling is working inside an svg here is an exemple of an svg i'm using:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 28">  <defs>
  <style>.cls-1{isolation:isolate;}.cls-2,.cls-3{fill:#ef8989;}.cls-3{mix-blend-mode:screen;}</style>
 </defs>
 <title>アセット 2</title>
 <g class="cls-1">
 <g id="レイヤー_2" data-name="レイヤー 2">
 <g id="レイヤー_1-2" data-name="レイヤー 1">
 <polygon class="cls-2" points="0 0 0 28 28 28 28 14 28 0 0 0"/><polygon class="cls-2" points="0 14 0 0 12.2 0 19.2 0 12.2 14 19.2 28 12.2 28 0 28 0 14"/>
 <polygon class="cls-3" points="28 28 28 14 28 0 19.2 0 12.2 14 19.2 28 28 28"/>
 </g>
 </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

And here is how i'm trying to move the inline style to an external css file :

```css
.cls-1 {
  isolation : isolate;
}
.cls-3 {
  mix-blend-mode : screen;
  fill : #ef8989;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
 <g class="cls-1">
  <polygon class="cls-2" points="0 0 0 28 28 28 28 14 28 0 0 0"/>
  <polygon class="cls-2" points="0 14 0 0 12.2 0 19.2 0 12.2 14 19.2 28 12.2 28 0 28 0 14"/>
  <polygon class="cls-3" points="28 28 28 14 28 0 19.2 0 12.2 14 19.2 28 28 28"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Obviously there is something I don't understand on how to translate inline style to CSS style, my guess is that my issue is around here: `.cls-1{isolation:isolate;}.cls-2,` 
I must have something to specify for the class `cls-2` but didn't manage to get my head around this.

Thanks for any clarification and sorry if the question has been already asked couldn't find anything about it.

Matth

Comment: You are using an external CSS file?  Then how is the SVG supposed to know there is styling somewhere else?  You would need to add a `<style>` element to the SVG, just as you would do for an HTML file.  If you didn't actually mean an external CSS file, then please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `.cls-2,` for the fill color.

Coma separated selectors in CSS means they all get the following defined styles.

```css
.cls-1{
    isolation:isolate;
}

.cls-2,
.cls-3{
    fill:#ef8989;
}

.cls-3{
    mix-blend-mode:screen;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 28">  <defs>
 </defs>
 <title>アセット 2</title>
 <g class="cls-1">
 <g id="レイヤー_2" data-name="レイヤー 2">
 <g id="レイヤー_1-2" data-name="レイヤー 1">
 <polygon class="cls-2" points="0 0 0 28 28 28 28 14 28 0 0 0"/><polygon class="cls-2" points="0 14 0 0 12.2 0 19.2 0 12.2 14 19.2 28 12.2 28 0 28 0 14"/>
 <polygon class="cls-3" points="28 28 28 14 28 0 19.2 0 12.2 14 19.2 28 28 28"/>
 </g>
 </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks now reading it, it seems so obvious, lake of experience probably.